# Unable to determine the size of an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Consider the following code in C:

```
int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])
```

`a` is of the type `char **` and its purpose to my code is as an array. It is guaranteed that `a` has more than one element. Somehow, `size` always obtains the value 1.

My initial guess is that the `a` in `sizeof(a)` is being treated as the first pointer instead of an array. How do I fix this?

Comment: `a` is not an array.

Comment: `a` is a pointer.  Its size is the size of a `char **` pointer. As [@immibis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902677/unable-to-determine-the-size-of-an-array-of-pointers#comment69018980_40902677) comments, it is not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From just a pointer, you can't know the size of the buffer/array it points to. You must always track/pass the size of an array yourself.

The trick you're trying to use only applies to *arrays* (which degrade to pointers). It is unfortunate that it can accidentally be applied to pointers. This is why the Linux kernel defines the following macro:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]) + __must_be_array(arr))
```

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L53

The `__must_be_array()` invokes some compiler-specific functionality to ensure the mistake you just made causes a compilation error, instead of an incorrect value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Only with arrays (variables declared with square brackets, like as `char x[80]`) will do this correctly. There is no way to determine the size of an area a pointer (a variable with declared with an asterisk, like `char *y`) points to. If you are passing an array into a function, the function either has to already know the size, or you need to pass the size in with the pointer.

So what is happening in your example is: `sizeof(a)` is the size of a pointer (to pointer to char) in your CPU's architecture; likely `8`. `sizeof(a[0])` is the size of the pointer (to char) - still `8`, because pointer size is pointer size, no matter what they point to. There is no way to promote a pointer to an array (although it is easy to go in the other direction and assign an array to a pointer).